# Saving tf.trainable_variables() using convert_variables_to_constants

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras model that I would like to convert to a Tensorflow protobuf (e.g. `saved_model.pb`).

This model comes from transfer learning on the vgg-19 network in which and the head was cut-off and trained with fully-connected+softmax layers while the rest of the vgg-19 network was frozen

I can load the model in Keras, and then use `keras.backend.get_session()` to run the model in tensorflow, generating the correct predictions:

```
frame = preprocess(cv2.imread("path/to/img.jpg")
keras_model = keras.models.load_model("path/to/keras/model.h5")

keras_prediction = keras_model.predict(frame)

print(keras_prediction)

with keras.backend.get_session() as sess:

    tvars = tf.trainable_variables()

    output = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Softmax:0')
    input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_1:0')

    tf_prediction = sess.run(output, {input_tensor: frame})
    print(tf_prediction) # this matches keras_prediction exactly
```

If I don't include the line `tvars = tf.trainable_variables()`, then the `tf_prediction` variable is completely wrong and doesn't match the output from `keras_prediction` at all. In fact all the values in the output (single array with 4 probability values) are exactly the same (~0.25, all adding to 1). This made me suspect that weights for the head are just initialized to 0 if `tf.trainable_variables()` is not called first, which was confirmed after inspecting the model variables. In any case, calling `tf.trainable_variables()` causes the tensorflow prediction to be correct.

The problem is that when I try to save this model, the variables from `tf.trainable_variables()` don't actually get saved to the `.pb` file:

```
with keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
    tvars = tf.trainable_variables()

    constant_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, sess.graph.as_graph_def(), ['Softmax'])
    graph_io.write_graph(constant_graph, './', 'saved_model.pb', as_text=False)
```

What I am asking is, how can I save a Keras model as a Tensorflow protobuf with the `tf.training_variables()` intact?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Would the following work? Loop through`keras_model.layers`, and for each one set `layer.trainable = False`. Then, compile the layers to a new keras model in a separate `h5` file, using that as the basis for converting to Tensorflow.

Comment: Just tried this...it didn't appear to work at all

Comment: Tried to reproduce the error from your code, but no success so far. Even without the line `tf.trainable_variables()`,  I'm seeing `tf_prediction` matches `keras_prediction`. Also, the final `Dense` layer is in the saved `.pb` file. Can you provide the code showing how you construct and save the model, and the version of Keras and TF you use?

Comment: Can you just try to run:
   `saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
   saver.save(sess, '/tmp/model/my_model')`
to save your model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So your approach of freezing the variables in the graph (converting to constants), should work, but isn't necessary and is trickier than the other approaches. (more on this below). If your want graph freezing for some reason (e.g. exporting to a mobile device), I'd need more details to help debug, as I'm not sure what implicit stuff Keras is doing behind the scenes with your graph. However, if you want to just save and load a graph later, I can explain how to do that, (though no guarantees that whatever Keras is doing won't screw it up..., happy to help debug that).

So there are actually two formats at play here. One is the `GraphDef`, which is used for Checkpointing, as it does not contain metadata about inputs and outputs. The other is a `MetaGraphDef` which contains metadata and a graph def, the metadata being useful for prediction and running a `ModelServer` (from tensorflow/serving).

In either case you need to do more than just call `graph_io.write_graph` because the variables are *usually* stored outside the graphdef.

There are wrapper libraries for both these use cases. [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) is primarily used for saving and restoring checkpoints.

However, since you want prediction, I would suggest using a [`tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/builder/SavedModelBuilder) to build a SavedModel binary. I've provided some boiler plate for this below:

```
from tensorflow.python.saved_model.signature_constants import DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY as DEFAULT_SIG_DEF
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder('./mymodel')
with keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
  output = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Softmax:0')
  input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_1:0')
  sig_def = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(
    {'input': input_tensor},
    {'output': output}
  )
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
      sess, tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING,
      signature_def_map={
        DEFAULT_SIG_DEF: sig_def
      }
  )
builder.save()
```

After running this code you should have a `mymodel/saved_model.pb` file as well as a directory `mymodel/variables/` with protobufs corresponding to the variable values.

Then to load the model again, simply use `tf.saved_model.loader`:

```
# Does Keras give you the ability to start with a fresh graph?
# If not you'll need to do this in a separate program to avoid
# conflicts with the old default graph
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()):
  meta_graph_def = tf.saved_model.loader.load(
      sess, 
      tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING,
      './mymodel'
  )
  # From this point variables and graph structure are restored

  sig_def = meta_graph_def.signature_def[DEFAULT_SIG_DEF]
  print(sess.run(sig_def.outputs['output'], feed_dict={sig_def.inputs['input']: frame}))
```

Obviously there's a more efficient prediction available with this code through tensorflow/serving, or Cloud ML Engine, but this should work.
It's possible that Keras is doing something under the hood which will interfere with this process as well, and if so we'd like to hear about it (and I'd like to make sure that Keras users are able to freeze graphs as well, so if you want to send me a gist with your full code or something maybe I can find someone who knows Keras well to help me debug.)

EDIT: You can find an end to end example of this here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/keras/trainer/model.py#L85

Comment: This is perfect, and it solved the problem I was having! Thanks so much!